# How to do a compareTo method for 3 circles?

Tags: java, compareto

I was trying to do a compareTo method that first sorts by radius. If that is the same, then sort by x-coordinate. If that is the same, then sort by y-coordinate.

The circle class has a constructor with Point, and (double) radius. I'm not really sure how to go about this since other compareTo methods on the internet are just comparing 2 objects.

Comment: You're still comparing two objects. The comparison simply involves three of their properties.

Comment: It's certain that you're doing too much in the compare. Just compareTo two objects there. It's misleading to do anything else if I understand you right.

Comment: You could implement `Comparable<Circle>` in your `Circle` class and define your own `compareTo` method.

Comment: ...also, please, provide the code for the compareTo that you were trying for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

When comparing multiple properties in order like that, you simply compare the first. If they are the same, then you compare the second. And if they are the same, then you compare the third.

Assuming you're using `java.awt.Point`, you do it like this:

```
class Circle implements Comparable<Circle> {
    private Point  point;
    private double radius;

    // ... code ...

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Circle that) {
        int cmp = Double.compare(this.radius, that.radius);
        if (cmp == 0)
            cmp = Double.compare(this.point.getX(), that.point.getX());
        if (cmp == 0)
            cmp = Double.compare(this.point.getY(), that.point.getY());
        return cmp;
    }

    // ... code ...
}
```

If you need to sort 3 circles, put them in an array and sort the array:

```
Circle[] circles = { new Circle(...),
                     new Circle(...),
                     new Circle(...) };
Arrays.sort(circles);
```